# Problemas tomando src de json con react

Tags: json, reactjs

Hola como va? Este es mi primer post. Les cuento el problema. Estoy aprendiendo react y empece a hacer una pagina. He generado componentes (< Button > en este caso) que me han funcionado bien, pero ahora he querido pasarle informacion a traves de un JSON a ese componente para que no este hardcodeada y me arroja el siguiente error:

**Error: Cannot find module '"../images/HomeFooter-Explorar.svg"'**

el tema es que cuando utilizo los componentes en forma directa sin el json, no me arroja el error

```
<Button text="Explorar" path={require("../images/HomeFooter-Explorar.svg")} link="tuBusqueda"></Button>
```

pero cuando tomo la informacion del json:

```
<div>
      {data.HomeButtons.map(aButton => 
                            <Button text={(aButton.text)} path={require(aButton.path)} />)}
                </div>
```

me arroja el error mencionado y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal

Simplifico los archivos para que se entienda mejor.

La estructura de directorios es la siguiente:

```
-Proyecto
--node_modules
--public
--src
---components
---css
---Data
---images
---pages
```

el archivo LocalData.json seria:

```
{
  "HomeButtons": [
    {
      "text" : "Explorar",
      "path" : "\"../images/HomeFooter-Explorar.svg\"",
      "link" : "tuBusqueda"
    }
  ]
}
```

el archivo app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from "../pages/Home";

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App
```

el archivo de la home.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../Data/LocalData'
import Button from "../components/Button";

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>
                    {data.HomeButtons.map(aButton => <Button text={(aButton.text)} path={require(aButton.path)}  />)}
               </div>
export default Home
```

y el componente Button.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "../css/Button.css"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className={"Button"}>
            <Link to={this.props.link}>
                <img src={this.props.path}/>
            </Link>
        </div>
    }
}

export default Button
```

Bueno desde ya estoy muy agradecido por cualquier ayuda que puedan darme.
Saludos.

Comment: quisiera saber si solucionaste tu problema o que solucion hallaste trate ya que tengo tu mismo problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el error está en como tienes escrito tu path en el JSON.

intenta con 
`"path" : "../images/HomeFooter-Explorar.svg",`

De la otra manera estás llamando `require('"../images/HomeFooter-Explorar.svg"')`, agregando comillas innecesarias.

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan pronto, si lo he probado tambien y me arroja el mismo error:
Error: Cannot find module '../images/HomeFooter-Explorar.svg'